# Spring Windows Authentication Sample fails to bind to LDAP

Tags: spring, security, ldap, bind, kerberos

We are trying to make the Spring Windows Authentication Module working on a SLES 11 SP3 system.

The User Authentication seems to work just fine:

```
2015-07-08 08:32:02.596 DEBUG 16861 --- [io-18080-exec-3] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider 
2015-07-08 08:32:02.596 DEBUG 16861 --- [io-18080-exec-3] .a.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider : Try to validate Kerberos Token
2015-07-08 08:32:02.966 DEBUG 16861 --- [io-18080-exec-3] .a.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider : Succesfully validated dummy@EXAMPLE.COM 
2015-07-08 08:32:02.967 DEBUG 16861 --- [io-18080-exec-3] o.s.s.l.s.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch      : Searching for user 'dummy@EXAMPLE.COM', with user search [ searchFilter: '(| (userPrincipalName={0}) (sAMAccountName={0}))', searchBase: 'OU=Users,OU=Custom,DC=example.com,DC=com', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ] Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is /usr/share/tomcat/conf/myapplication.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP/myapplication.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false principal is HTTP/myapplication.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
Will use keytab
Commit Succeeded
```

Then the attempt to search for the user in our LDAP/ActiveDirectory fails:

```
2015-07-08 08:17:02.999 DEBUG 16584 --- [io-18080-exec-3] o.s.l.c.support.AbstractContextSource    : Got Ldap context on server 'ldaps://windc1.example.com:636/'
2015-07-08 08:17:03.050 DEBUG 16584 --- [io-18080-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2015-07-08 08:17:03.050 DEBUG 16584 --- [io-18080-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2015-07-08 08:17:03.056 ERROR 16584 --- [io-18080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0907     2B, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580]; remaining name 'OU=Users,OU=Custom,DC=example.com,DC=com'
```

My application.yml file looks like this:

```
server:
    port: 18080
app:
    ad-domain: EXAMPLE.COM
    ad-server: ldaps://windc1.example.com:636/
    service-principal: HTTP/myapplication.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
    keytab-location: /usr/share/tomcat/conf/myapplication.keytab
    ldap-search-base: OU=Users,OU=Custom,DC=example.com,DC=com
    ldap-search-filter: "(| (userPrincipalName={0}) (sAMAccountName={0}))"
```

I checked verified the service-principal and the keytab to produce valid tokens but this seems to have no influence to the LDAP module which should from my understanding always try to bind to the directory.

As you may allready noticed I am very new to this stuff and I appreciate every suggestion.

Thx a lot

Regards

Dominik